# How do I make an input change it's value to it's id?

Tags: javascript, input

I want to make a button that shows the answers of some questions, but for the input boxes I made it so the id of the input box also is the answer. So I've been trying to make the text change to it's ID but it doesn't work, I don't know what's wrong, can anyone help me?

```
function bereken(){

    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i=0; i<x.length;i++){

        document.getElementById(x[i].id).value = x[i].id;

    }

}
```

Comment: On the whole, though not very efficient, this should work. The problem might be in your HTML. Add that as well.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Besides you can just use

```
x[i].value = x[i].id;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cs4tz/1/

Comment: Thanks, that works :) And now I know I can test stuff with fiddle ^^

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have more than one question with the same answer, then your system will have duplicate IDs. This is bad.

Instead, use a `data` attribute to hold the answer:

```
<input type="text" data-answer="Forty-two" />
```

Then change your JS to this:

```
for( i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    x[i].value = x[i].getAttribute("data-answer");
}
```